# Changing File Explorer Background Color Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, colors, color-theme

I want to change the white flourish background color of default file explorer in `Windows 8.1 Pro`.

Its hard to see white background color every time people with weak eye-sight or for continuous laptop users.

Is there a way to change default white background color for file explorer in `Windows 8.1` ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to change the background of the Windows File Explorer is to select one of the dark High Contrast Themes of Windows.

To do so, open the Context Menu of the Desktop and select Personalize. In the Personalization windows, select one of the dark High Contrast Themes.

Alas, this will not only change the background of the Windows File Explorer but also almost all of the appearance of Windows. Fortunately you can change a lot of it according your preference.

Comment: Indeed. It changes all of the Windows to the classic theme, but even more importantly, it uses a solid triple-black (0-0-0) which is just too damn harsh. We need to be able to set it to something softer like 30-30-30. 